# Pass complex object to ui-sref params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**I need build url like this:** 
/list?filter[status]=1&filter[type]=2

I do:

#### link:

`<a ui-sref="list({filter: {status: 1, type:2}})">List</a>`

(pass complex object in params, if pass simple object - {filter: 1} - it ok, but I need this)

#### state:

```
.state('list', {
    url:        '/list?filter',
    …
})
```

In total I get url like:

```
/list?filter=[object Object]
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wV3ieKyc5WGnjqw42p7y?p=preview

**How I can fix it?**

Comment: This could be some what duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router

Comment: in your situation you dont need to pass a complex object to ui-sref. filter is not parent of type and status. filter is just a static keyword in url. just pass {type: 1, status: 2}

Comment: I think this is better way, passing object params as hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UI-Router` is now shipped with support for **`custom types`** of params. There is [updated and working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwowXoPBc0VWm6ZY8NFc?p=preview) of your plunker.

So, we can adjust the state def like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('list', {
    url: 'list?{filter:CoolParam}',
```

As we can see, the filter is now of type **`CoolParam`**. Here we will define it:

```
app.config(['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($urlMatcherFactory) {

  $urlMatcherFactory.type('CoolParam',
  {
     name : 'CoolParam',
     decode: function(val)  { return typeof(val) ==="string" ? JSON.parse(val) : val;},
     encode: function(val)  { return JSON.stringify(val); },
     equals: function(a, b) { return this.is(a) && this.is(b) 
                                  && a.status === b.status && a.type == b.type },
     is: function(val)      { return angular.isObject(val) 
                                  && "status" in val && "type" in val },
  })

}]);
```

And now the `{{$stateParams}}` of a link like this:

```
<a ui-sref="list({filter: {status: 1, type:2}})">Click me to see params</a>
```

will return:

```
{"filter":{"status":1,"type":2}}
```

*NOTE: In this case I made my life easier, and simply converted json into string. This means, that url encoded param will look like this:*

```
#/list?filter=%7B%22status%22:1,%22type%22:2%7D
```

*which is `{"status":1,"type":2}`*

*But we can provide also other ways how to express our filter object*

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwowXoPBc0VWm6ZY8NFc?p=preview)

Also related Q & A:

- [Angular ui router parse query params into booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422981/1679310)
- [What is the correct way to use the “bool” param type with ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182177/1679310)

So, the above solution is nicely working with filter as a JSON. But in case that we must have url like this `?filter[status]=1&filter[type]=2`, we have to define the state differently. Each parameter must be declared as a separated simple type

```
$stateProvider.state('list2', {
    url: 'list2?state&type',
})
```

But in this case we would have it like this `?status=1&type=2`. This mapping is also part of this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwowXoPBc0VWm6ZY8NFc?p=preview).

Comment: Now you can just use standard "json" type. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/027f1fcf9c0916cea651e88981345da6f9ff214a

url: 'list?{filter:json}'

Comment: @shlensky That's worth an answer. Make it one, and I'm sure you'll get upvotes for it.