# ionic framework, how to pass more than one param object in state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I Would like to pass two object in **state.go** method like this:

```
$state.go('app.home', {
            playSavedPlaylist:true,
            playlistData: dataToPass
        });
```

State app.home is following:

```
.state('app.home', {
      url: '/home:playSavedPlaylist:playlistData',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

But if i'm trying to get params using:

```
console.log($stateParams);
```

I always get following:

```
Object {playSavedPlaylist: "true[object Object]", playlistData: ""}
```

**But should it be:**

```
  Object {playSavedPlaylist: "true", playlistData: [object Object]}
```

How can i do it in right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe this could also be of your intereset: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27659582/1679310

Answer (score 2):

You can add '/' to separate between parameters. Also url parameters can only be integers and strings, therefore objects must be converted to json, or not being included in the url.

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home/:playSavedPlaylist/:playlistData',
    views: {
        'menuContent' :{
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    }
});

$state.go('app.home', {
    playSavedPlaylist:true,
    playlistData: angular.toJson(dataToPass)
}
//, { location: false, inherit: false}    <-- will exclude parameters from url
);
```

Comment: It was first thing what i tried, but it is causing black screen without any error.

Answer (score 0):

What is `dataToPass` ? an object?

You can't pass an object directly in the URL, so you should use a service in order to get the data that you need, you can only pass integer (ex: id, max, min) and string that doesn't contains forbidden char for URL (You can use URI encode).