# Angular $injector:modulerr for ui-router $urlServiceProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ui-router with Angular 1.5. I want to add a customer parameter type like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422981. I have read that `$urlMatcherFactory.type()` has been deprecated in favour of `$urlService.config.type()`.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$urlServiceProvider', function($urlService) {
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

You can see above, and in this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Rk6WRAEUfpUFwyZhnAH0 that `$urlServiceProvider` cannot be injected, even though it can be found in the documentation here https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_urlserviceprovider

I have tried using the older `$urlMatcherFactory.type()` but, while the injection process works, it doesn't register any new type I give it (like the boolean from the linked Stack Overflow answer).

Can anyone help me create a new parameter type with angular-ui-router? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated link to your plunkr code, error resolved

https://plnkr.co/edit/cPUAnIQzVFOpsa0xWkJk?p=preview

```
   <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I can't use version 1.0 of ui-router in my app. Is there a way of getting `$urlMatcherFactory.type()` to work?